# Google Device Access Console Application In Review

Tags: nest-device-access, google-sdm-api

I have done the device access registration and created a project. I have submitted the project for commercial use. But my application is in review since 3-4 days.

Can anyone help how long it will take? If anywhere else I can get help?

The gmail id is theresidencevvc105@gmail.com
Project id is 17aa27cc-e0f6-4428-8738-9f8a97640e79

Comment: Anyone can please help? Still my project is in review.

Comment: Its been about 10 days since i applied for commercial development as well. Is there a way to reach out to the team? Havent heard anything at all, not even a mail stating I applied. How long usually they take? Can somebody help?

Comment: @sagar For me also, I posted on multiple forums, contacted google support but they denied to help as they mentioned its not in their scope.

Comment: thats not at all good to hear, i am realizing Microsoft is way better in this regard. At least they provide a way to reach out to the relevant team.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not hear back on your certification request in a timely manner please reach out to our developer support team by creating a ticket on the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

I checked your application. We have communicated the results in mid May through the developer email of your project. if you have any additional questions feel free to respond through email.